# Appending data to Blob with hibernate without using much memory

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, blob

I have a `java.sql.Blob` (~200MB) in my Postgres DB loaded via hibernate. How can I **append** data from an input stream to that `Blob` in database without loading it completely into memory (I don't have much RAM)?

```
@Entity
public class Ressource implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Lob
    private Blob data;
}
```

Comment: No idea how to do this on the Hibernate side, but at the PostgreSQL end you could store your data as large objects instead, giving you a file-like interface to them. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html . Maybe Hibernate has mapping options that lets you tell it to store BLOBs as large objects instead of `bytea` fields?

Comment: yes large objects are streams, so they can be eeeked and appended easily, bytea columns are table columns and so cannot.

Comment: is the ram shoortage on the client or on the server?

Comment: The Java client using the db via hibernate is low in memory. The db has enough ram ans harddisk.